# HERE Maps dropped support for China map?

Tags: javascript, here-api

So I have embedded HERE Maps with theirs JS API to my website. Everything was working ok until today. Now only main roads are visible when looking at China cities like Beijing (3rd ring, 4th ring,..).

If I got check at public maps page (https://www.here.com/?map=39.98318,116.34231,16,normal) then it is still working but as embedded map it is not.

Did HERE Maps drop support for China?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use http://heremaps.cn instead.

In leaflet.js you can set like this:

> //{s}.maps.nlp.nokia.com.cn/maptile/2.1/" + "maptile/{mapID}/{variant}/{z}/{x}/{y}/256/png8?" + "app_id={your_app_id}&app_code={your_app_code}

Answer (score 0):

There might be some legal restriction which prevent you from using Maps in China. Please reach out to your HERE account executive to get more details, or use the contact us form on developer.here.com https://developer.here.com/contact-us